# PDO How to select where two values from different arrays in 2 different colums

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo, printf

I got 2 columns in my database that hold text (`Products Code` and `Products Variant`).

for example:
`Products Code` holds the following text: C050101, C070104
and 
`Products Variant` holds the following text: RED, NULL

I want to select all the rows `WHERE Code = Products Code AND Variant = Products Variant`.
bases on the example I wrote above, I should get 2 rows:
first row `WHERE Code=C050101 and Variant=RED`
second row `WHERE Code=C070104 and Variant IS NULL` << **IS NULL**

I have no idea how to do it...
I would know how to do it if I only need to select only all the rows `WHERE Code = Products Code` >>

```
$arr = array('C050101','C070104');
$inclause = implode(',',array_fill(0,count($arr),'?'));
$stockstmt = $pdo->prepare(sprintf("SELECT `id`, `WebTitle`, `StockCode` FROM `stock` WHERE `StockCode` IN(%s)",$inclause));
$stockstmt->execute($arr);
```

I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like `WHERE code in (select ProductsCode from table)`?  Your question is confusing on what does/doesn't work.

Comment: I didnt say that something is not working. I just want to select using  more complicated query than I posted above.. something like `WHERE (Code="C050101" AND Variant="RED") OR (Code="C070104" AND Variant IS NULL)`

Comment: Well, that kind of is your answer right there, isn't it? Generate the query dynamically by adding the two fields to query by, or create a temporary table to join against on both fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `IN` predicate for this because `IN` only knows how to compare with `=` and you need to compare differently to handle the NULLs.

MySQL has a non-standard [null-safe equal operator `<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) which knows that NULL=NULL is true, and NULL = 'RED' is false.

If you use something other than MySQL, your RDBMS might support `IS [NOT] DISTINCT` which is standard SQL syntax for a similar predicate.

I tested the following and it works:

```
$arr = array('C050101','RED', 'C070104', NULL);

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `WebTitle`, `StockCode` FROM `stock`
  WHERE (`StockCode`, `StockVariant`) <=> (?, ?)
     OR (`StockCode`, `StockVariant`) <=> (?, ?)";

$stockstmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
if ($stockstmt === false) { die(print_r($pdo->errorInfo(), true)); }

$status = $stockstmt->execute($arr);
if ($status === false) { die(print_r($stockstmt->errorInfo(), true)); }
```

I'll leave it to you how you want to build a list of predicates.

---

Re your comment:

It's not a recommended practice to use the literal string 'NULL' to represent a missing or inapplicable value.  That's what NULL is for in SQL.

If you want a function that makes it more dynamic to build the predicates, try this:

```
function lookformultiplethings(array $arr)
{
  global $pdo;

  $where = array();
  $values = array();
  foreach ((array) $arr as $term) {
    $where[] = '('
        . join(',', array_map(function ($col) {return "`$col`";}, array_keys($term)))
        . ') <=> ('
        . join(',', array_fill(0,count($term),'?'))
        . ')';
    $values = array_merge($values, array_values($term));
  }
  $sql = "SELECT `id`, `WebTitle`, `StockCode` FROM `stock` ";
  if ($where) {
    $sql .= "WHERE " . join(' OR ', $where);
  }

  $stockstmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  if ($stockstmt === false) { die(print_r($pdo->errorInfo(), true)); }

  $status = $stockstmt->execute($values);
  if ($status === false) { die(print_r($stockstmt->errorInfo(), true)); }

  print_r($stockstmt->fetchAll());
}

lookformultiplethings(array(
  array('StockCode' => 'C050101', 'StockVariant' => 'RED'),
  array('StockCode' => 'C070104', 'StockVariant' => 'NULL'),
));
```

Be careful that the keys of the array you pass are legitimate column names.  That is, don't let user input ever set the column names unless you verify it against a whitelist of real columns.

Comment: my NULL is NULL as text > `$arr = array('C050101','RED', 'C070104', 'NULL');` though u gave here nice solution, combining the two arrays into one array which every odd key contain the code and every even key contain the variant and using the query in your format. Yet, your solution is not dynamic, u are being bases on that there are only 2 codes and 2 variants, I need something more dynamic